# ChromeDriver click button throw exception

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-chromedriver

I am using ChromeDriver to inspect and request to process data. I can see all the steps carried out successfully but throw exception when it come to 'Click button' to generate report. not sure what it does meaning here

[image]

`error`

```
element click intercepted: Element <input id="generate_report_button" class="ImageButtonWide" name="report" type="button" value="Generate Report" onclick="redirectGenerate(jQuery(this))"> is not clickable at point (525, 658). Other element would receive the click: <div class="cc-cookies " id="eu_cookie_bar">...</div>
```

(Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.45)

`Code`

```
using (ChromeDriver window = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions))
{
    try
    {

    var btnReport = window.FindElement(By.Name("report"));
    log.Debug("Found 'report' button");
    
    // remaining code 
    new SelectElement(selFormat).SelectByValue("csv");
    log.Info("Selected 'csv' from 'format' select list");

    btnReport.Click();
    log.Debug("Clicked 'report' button");
```

[image]

Comment: You're trying to click an element, [btnReport], which "is not clickable". But you're not showing us the code which sets up [btnReport], which code might explain *why* [btnReport] isn't clickable.

Comment: I have update code in the question

Comment: var btnReport = window.FindElement(By.Name("report"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can attempt to force click button using Actions API :

```
 Actions action = new Actions(IWebDriver);
 action.Click(IWebElement).Build().Perform();
```

you get this error - "element is not clickable at point (525, 658). Other element would receive the click" when two elements are overlapping and webdriver warns you that the desired element might not receive the click.

Comment: thanks for the support but where I give btnReport reference in your above code

Comment: Actions action = new Actions(window);  // window is your webDriver instance 
action.Click(btnReport).Build().Perform(); // btnReport is your IWebElement